# How do I access a variable from Bamboo in a Gradle script?

Tags: variables, gradle, arguments, parameter-passing, bamboo

I am creating a deployment in Bamboo. I have some variables set up under the deployment plan. How can I access these from a Gradle script? There is an arguments input (that I guess I would use something like variable=${bamboo.variable} in there, but I cant work out how to get them to go through to the script (at the moment just doing something like prinln varible to get them out). How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, Bamboo exports all it's variable into the build environment. In that case, you can get any variable within the script as follows:

```
System.getenv('bamboo.variable')
```

Alternatively, you may pass it into the build as build script parameter, like so:

```
-Pvariable=${bamboo.variable}
```

and then you can get it within a script as a project property:

```
println variable
```

Comment: The first option didn't work (first thing I did was try that and other variants of it), however the second option did work (I had left out the P when I tried it). Thanks for that.

Comment: First option works with System.getenv('bamboo_variable')
Just replace dot with underscore.